# Using CDC to detect changes in table definitions (DDL)

Tags: streaming-api, change-data-capture

Can I use Capture Data Changes to get notifications on changes in the Salesforce table definitions, such as Add Column?

Thanks in advance

Comment: CDC is used to capture changes in data not metadata.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** [Change Data Capture](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_intro.htm) publishes only record (data) changes. You cannot use Change Data Capture to publish/subscribe to any *metadata* changes, viz., adding a field to an object.

> Change Data Capture publishes change events, which represent changes to Salesforce records.